# How to tell gwt-maven-plugin not to use certain parameters when calling the GWT-compiler

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am trying to migrate a GWT-2.0.2 project to the net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin, but it seems to be calling the GWT-compiler with parameters that weren't recognized back in times of GWT 2.0.2, like -deploy, -sourceLevel etc.

I know it is possible to add extra parameters, but is it possible to exclude some?

Comment: The GWT version is much older than the plugin. I would advise to update to the latest GWT version. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is way older. But an upgrade is a no-go, as it would mean also to upgrade the UI-library the app was built with... way over the budget :(

Comment: In case the application is build with GXT 2, it can be done with a relative small amount of work.

Comment: @ElHoss SmartGWT

Comment: Never used SmartGWT.

Comment: my experience with it back in the days was pretty underwhelming to say the least, that's why I don't want to spend any extra time working in it (which includes any amount of work needed for an upgrade to whatever is the current version)

Comment: You should take a look at DominoKit/domino-ui. Very nice stuff.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to upgrade the plugin to something so new, but can't upgrade anything else - is there some benefit you are trying to get?

Comment: The old plugin did not work with any Java I had installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/main/src/main/java/net/ltgt/gwt/maven/GwtOptions.java

````java
  class CommandlineBuilder {
    public static List<String> buildArgs(Log log, GwtOptions options) {
      List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
      if (options.getLogLevel() != null) {
        args.add("-logLevel");
        args.add(options.getLogLevel());
      }
      args.add("-war");
      args.add(options.getWarDir().getAbsolutePath());
      args.add("-workDir");
      args.add(options.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath());
      args.add("-deploy");
      args.add(options.getDeployDir().getAbsolutePath());```
````